# how do i put my native libraries on obj/local

Tags: android, android-ndk

So, I already made an Android.mk file and I think it's already doing it's job. I'm using .so files and I don't have the source files for them.

This is my Android.mk file.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := wfdsinkemu
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/armeabi-v7a/libwfdsinkemu.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/armeabi-v7a/libgstreamer_android.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This is my Application.mk file.

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
APP_STL := c++_shared
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := jni/Android.mk
APP_MODULES := libgstreamer_android libwfdsinkemu
```

But I think the native libraries are still not copied on the obj/local folder because the app still crashes with a UnsatisfiedLinkError.

I'm already using ReLinker it still shows this error.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libgstreamer_android.so" not found
```

BTW, I'm trying to make this work on an android box running nougat.

After downgrading my targetSdkVersion from 26 to 22, it worked with I think an error displayed using an AlertDialog. The error is

```
Detected problems with app native libraries
(please consult log for detail):
libwfdsinkemu.so: invalid DT_NEEDED entry "./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libgstreamer_android.so"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell gradle that you have prebuilt NDK libraries.

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#jniLibs

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs 'imported-lib/src/', 'more-imported-libs/src/'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So apparently, nougat or from marshmallow up to current latest android api(nougat), google changed some security policies making the use of native libraries difficult to implement.

After some research, I found an answer that says that I need to make my `targetSdkVersion` to 22(originally 26). After making the changes, it already worked. It seems like it's a bug on the android api marshmallow and up. I hope they make the use of native libraries easier on the coming version.

Comment: Which policy changes are you talking about specifically? Note that starting November 1, you will no longer be able to publish updated versions of your app unless the new version has a `targetSdkVersion` of 26 or higher ([source](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk)).